# Unable to connect to the remote server with HTMLworker

Tags: c#, .net, itext, webrequest

I m developing a web application in C# and using itextsharp.text elements.
I m very much new to itextsharp and its classes.
Please Help me with this error:
***Unable to connect to the remote server***

Here is my code and stack trace:

```
public void CreatePDFDocument(string strHtml) 
{
        DirectoryInfo thisFolder = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("Temp"));
        if (thisFolder.Exists)
        {
            if (File.Exists(Server.MapPath("Temp/test.pdf")))
            {
                File.Delete(Server.MapPath("Temp/test.pdf"));
            }

            thisFolder.Delete();
            thisFolder.Create();
        }
        else
        {
            thisFolder.Create();

        }
        string strFileName =Server.MapPath("Temp/test.pdf");
        // step 1: creation of a document-object
        Document document = new Document();
        // step 2:
        // we create a writer that listens to the document
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(strFileName, FileMode.Create));
        StringReader se = new StringReader(strHtml);
        HTMLWorker obj = new HTMLWorker(document);
        document.Open();
        obj.Parse(se); // this line throws error
        document.Close();
        ShowPdf(strFileName);
}
```

The line in BOLD throws error.

Here is the stack trace:

> System.Net.WebException occurred
>
> HResult=-2146233079
>
> Message=Unable to connect to the remote server
>
> Source=System
>
> StackTrace:   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
>
> at iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(Uri url, Boolean
>   handleIncorrectImage)
>
> at iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(Uri url)
>
> at iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(String filename)
>
> at
>   iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.ElementFactory.CreateImage(String
>   src,  IDictionary`2 attrs, ChainedProperties chain, IDocListener
>   document, IImageProvider img_provider, Dictionary`2 img_store, String
>   img_baseurl)   at
>   iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker.CreateImage(IDictionary`2
>   attrs)
>
> at
>   iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLTagProcessors.HTMLTagProcessor_IMG.StartElement(HTMLWorker
>   worker, String tag, IDictionary`2 attrs)
>
> at iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker.StartElement(String
>   tag, IDictionary`2 attrs)
>
> at
>   iTextSharp.text.xml.simpleparser.SimpleXMLParser.ProcessTag(Boolean
>   start)
>
> at iTextSharp.text.xml.simpleparser.SimpleXMLParser.Go(TextReader
>   reader)
>
> at
>   iTextSharp.text.xml.simpleparser.SimpleXMLParser.Parse(ISimpleXMLDocHandler
>   doc, ISimpleXMLDocHandlerComment comment, TextReader r, Boolean html)
>
> at iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker.Parse(TextReader
>   reader)
>
> at Payroll.PaySlip.CreatePDFDocument(String strHtml) in F:\New
>   folder\EMS\EMS\Payroll\PaySlip.aspx.cs:line 88
>
> InnerException: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException
>
> HResult=-2147467259
>
> Message=No connection could be made because the target machine
>   actively refused it 127.0.0.1:5510
>
> Source=System
>
> ErrorCode=10061
>
> NativeErrorCode=10061
>
> StackTrace:   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint
>   endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
>
> at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean
>   connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress&
>   address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult,
>   Exception& exception)
>
> InnerException:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unsure without content of HTML, but is this applicable to you: 
http://forums.asp.net/t/1841173.aspx ?

quote from that page:

> As your html string contain Images that are pointing to some external
>   server.  and iTextSharp library is trying to get images from those
>   server and failed to do so, that's why you are getting those error.
>
> Try to acces thorse images from your browser in same machine.

Comment: But that did not help..! m having trouble to write this test.pdf with some HTML contents. (Please help.. Thanks in advance)

Comment: does anybody know more about this?

Comment: Well, theres not much info to work on. Its a late reaction now, but are you developing a web project on development server with port 5510?
If so, do you have Firewall or something blocking your calls? There seems to be nothing listening on that port..

Comment: No.. My development server is not using 5510.. Everything works well n good except the line `obj.Parse(se);`. Do you thing my definition for HTMLworker follows correct signature or having correct arguments? Though i have checked it before, but your opinion counts!

Comment: Your logs' Message above states that the code is trying to connect to 127.0.0.1:5510 (your local pc, port 5510)
What does your Server.MapPath variabele say? Im betting it is giving the wrong path (127.0.0.1:5510, instead of the port you are using). 

Does the code live in another Web Project in your visual studio?